# Libgdx on Android with proper disposing

Tags: android, libgdx, dispose

I'm currently not happy with my dispose() implementation for a libgdx game for android.

What i'm doing at the moment, is loading all my assets in an assetmanager when my app is launched, pass it around and use the assets.

I tested two different things: First i didnt dispose at all, so when the app is closed via android back or home and reopened everything is working fine and the current screen is displayed correctly. I'm not sure what happens to the assets in this case. They should remain in memory,and can be reused when the app is resumed. But what happens if android kills the app in background. I guess i get a memory leak than ?

So i tried disposing in the onPause() callback and reload the assets in the onResume().Now my screen wasnt rendered anymore, so i think i had to rebuild it completly, cause the assetmanager.get(...) in the scene2d actors contrustors now have to be updated ? So i tried building the scenegraph in the show() method, which didnt work out, cause my gamelogic from which the screen gets its data now threw alot of errors. I worked around that with just restarting from the menu when the user exits the app and resumes, which im not happy with either.

Additionally i create bitmapfonts with FreeTypeFontGenerator on the fly in different parts of my screens, which i dispose() when hiding the screen. So, i guess i have a problem here too, when the app is closed and later destroyed by android ?

Comment: The dispose() callback of the ApplicationAdapter (Game) is called when the application is ended. Is it insufficient to dispose() resources only then?

Comment: What does "ended" mean ? When the application is paused due too android  home or back button, or when the application is actually killed by android cause its not used for a longer period of time.

Comment: Smart people use the Back button to exit an application, not the Home button. Home doesn't "exit" the app, it puts it in the activity stack in the background, and gets ended after inactivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dispose in the `dispose` method of your Game/Screen/ApplicationListener. This is called by Android when the Activity finishes and is the proper place to dispose of all the native memory. It is done automatically.

You cannot expect to be able to reuse loaded textures after an Activity finishes and a new one is created, so make sure your assets are loaded in the `create` method of your Game/ApplicationListener, not `resume`.

A memory leak will not happen as a result of Android killing your application in the background. Android is able to reclaim all memory from your application when it kills it. But if your Activity is closed without your total application being killed, then you will leak stuff that was not properly disposed.

A memory leak in LibGDX happens when you are using any class that implements Disposable, and you don't dispose of it when you're done using it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i now just create my assetmanager in the game create() and dispose it in the game dispose(). The different screens dispose() actually isnt called when the app is destroyed, are u sure the game dispose() IS ? Which brings me to another problem: My fonts are not saved in the assetmanger but created on the fly in every screen. I dispose them in the screens dispose() which is called from the screens hide(). But this is not happening when the app is closed. Do i leak something there ?

Comment: Addionally i dont quite understand why i even have to dispose() in the game dispose(). As i understand, this method is called when android kills my activity, but as u stated android reclaims all memory in that case either way. Or is there a diffrence between killing the activity and killing the app ?

Comment: If you have more than one screen loaded, the Game object doesn't know to dispose of the ones that are not on screen, so you should call dispose on the non-active ones manually. So yes, you are leaking those screens contents.

Comment: There's a distinction between Activity's and Applications. When you press back to exit an Activity, it gets finished. If you have failed to dispose of assets in your Game's `dispose` method, they will be leaked in this case. But if Android kills your entire application, it will reclaim all memory regardless of what you failed to dispose correctly. I edited the answer to clarify it. My point is, your app can't bring down the whole OS by leaking memory. Eventually the OS will just kill your app and reclaim all the memory automatically.